# Print a 2D array in a certain way in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, printing, 2d

I want to print a 2D array like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]` for example.
I generate this 2D array by appending arrays, for example the next one I add could be `np.array([7, 8, 9])`.
Finally, I perform `np.array()` on the final 2D object a.

I use `np.array2string(a, separator=',')` to print it, but then I get something like `[array([1, 2, 3]), array(...), ...]`

If I append the arrays as `np.array2string([7,8,9], separator=',')` and then print using `np.array2string()` I get `['[1,2,3]','[4,5,6]',...]`

In reality, there are much more rows and columns and that's why there is probably a `\n` too like in
`['[1, \n 2,3]','[4, \n5,6]',...]`

So finally what I actually want is python to print it like `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`. So no words like 'array', no quotation marks, and actually also no `\n`. And separation by commas.

I have not found a solution yet. Does someone know a way for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could just convert it to a plain Python list and print that:

```
print(a.tolist())
```

To add some line breaks automatically and make the output more readable if it is very long, you can use the *pretty-printing* module from the standard library:

```
from pprint import pprint

pprint(a.tolist())
```

Comment: Yes indeed, this seemed to be the thing I was looking for. Thanks.
Maybe side note, is there a way to fully print it on the screen, because now it is printed as one long line way outside the screen. This is not really an issue but would be a bonus.